# Install make on an offline server without apt-offline

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

My goal is to set up an Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Server to connect to the internet without spending extra money. I can't plug the server into an ethernet connection, because I'm currently residing at a university where they charge you a monthly rate for an ethernet connection.

I have an old IEEE 802.11n Wifi dongle that I'd like to use instead, which comes with a driver I have to install. The issue is, the driver's installation requires make, which apparently Ubuntu Server OSes do not come preloaded with, the package doesn't exist according to it. I was recommended to use apt-offline to download the packages on a computer with an internet connection then send them over, but it requires that the offline server has the apt-offline package, which it also does not. The only other solution I could find was to use Keryx which does the same job as apt-offline, but it seems they stopped updating their software and supported Ubuntu versions around the same time apt-offline came out.

My question is, is there a way to get make installed on my computer so I can get an internet connection which doesn't require already having an internet connection, that also doesn't require extra money or taking the server outside to scrounge for a free ethernet connection?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS you can install the [build-essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/build-essential) (`make` including `gcc`, `g++`, `libc6` etc. and its dependencies) and 
the [linux-headers](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-headers-4.10.0-14) package from the installation CD ([ubuntu-16.04.6-server-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.6-server-amd64.iso)).

To install them, you need to uncomment the first line starting with `# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.6 LTS...` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` in line 3, then mount your optical drive and install the packages:

```
# replace /dev/sr0 with your device
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If you don't have an optical drive and you need to add the repository of your USB installer or the ISO file itself, see

- [How to make USB drive as local repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/947299)
- [How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/a/181178)